# SSIS - Error Output doesn't contain the value which is erroring

Tags: error-handling, ssis

I have a source connection which is a ADO.NET MySql, I execute a stored procedure on MYSQL connection which gives me the data set, as we know SSIS tries to read the data from few rows and define the metadata when I run this procedure it defines the data based on data which it receives, however I run this procedure  in loops for different sites (server and connection details are parameterized) columns and data types are same for all the sites, since SSIS reads only few columns while defining the metadata it doesn't get the data length and precision's correctly and they error out at the source connection itself, I am writing these errors to the flat file to process them later, when SSIS writes the error it replaces actual value with NULL.

**For Example** for  column which is defined as Numeric(4,2) when it encounters the values such as 243.32 instead of writing the actual value to error file it writes a NULL value.

Is there anyway we can make SSIS write the actual value to the error file, Below is the Job Flow, Appreciate any inputs on how we can handle this,

[image]

Explained in the details of the problem

Comment: If you click the source there is output columns for the success and one for failure section and they have data types there.  You should be able to override them the data types there and set them instead of letting SSIS determine them for you.  If you update the types (especially for the error output) to be generic (all VARCHAR) that may fix the issue.

Comment: Brad, Thank you for your response, I am not sure what you mean, I have option to change the data type in advanced editor for external columns, however when I ran the process again it gets reset again based on the data which procedure outputs I am not sure how to override that, also I am not sure how to update data type for error output it doesn't allow  me to that it gives me below error,                                      
The data type of output columns on the MySQL JP Shrdr DB cannot be changed, except for DT_WSTR and DT_NTEXT columns.

Comment: I work with MSSQL so there may be differences with how SSIS handles this.  I do know another way I was able to force SSIS to set the data types with when calling an SP (if you are using that) was to use parameter for SP WITH RESULTSETS (thought not sure if MySQL supports this)

Comment: Example for With RESULT SETS here:  https://www.w3computing.com/sqlserver2012/execute-statement-result-sets-clause/

Comment: Brad, Unfortunately WITH RESULTSETS or something similar is not available in MYSQL, If I can make SSIS to write the error value correctly instead of null that will mostly resolve my issue.